# How to optimize a mongodb geospatial query?

Tags: mongodb

A while ago I build the website crowdfundstats.com during a hackathon. The website gives some interesting insides based on the 130.000 or so kickstarter project data that we have scraped. The most interesting feature is the http://crowdfundstats.com/map.html on which you can drag a radius on the worldmap to get information on projects within that radius.

I use the aggregate function to find all projects within the radius based on their geospatial information. Each project has a geo location in the following format:

```
{ g1 :
    { type : "Point" },
    { coordinates : [ -83.102840423584, 42.354639053345] }     
}
```

The aggregate function then returns the total amount of backers, the average duration, the success percentage and the total amount of projects within the radius:

```
{'$match' : 
    {g1 :
        {$geoWithin :
            { $centerSphere :[[parseFloat(long), parseFloat(lat) ], radius/6371 ] 
            }
        }
    }
},
{'$group':
    {   "_id":"",
        "backers":    {"$sum": "$backers"},
        "dateDiff2":  {"$avg": "$dateDiff2"},
        "completed":  {"$avg": "$completed"},    
        "total":      {"$sum": 1}
    }
}
```

The issue is that the result of the query takes a long time (for example: more than 10 seconds when dragging the radius over the UK ). I have already added an 2dsphere index to increase speed, but this has almost no effect:

```
{
    "g1" : "2dsphere"
}
```

Is there anything I can do to optimise the query, or is this the expected performance on geospatial queries?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on this thread, I have improved the most heavy query from 15 seconds to 0.5seconds by upgrading from MongoDB 3.0 to 3.2. They have improved geospatial querying immensely. you can read more about it on the [MongoDB blog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/geospatial-performance-improvements-in-mongodb-3-2)